# Doubt in the question 8 section 8.1 (Hoffman and Kunze linear algebra book)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) and I'm having troubles how to prove this exercise on page 276:

[image]

I didn't understand why $f_A(X,Y)=f_A(Y,X)$. Even if I assume $A=A^t$ I can't get the symmetry of the real inner product.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $$f_A(Y, X) = X^TAY = X^TA^TY = Y^TAX = f_A(X, Y)$$

Comment: @NP-hard Why $X^TA^TY=Y^TAX$?

Comment: $X^TA^TY$ is a real number, so its transpose equals itself.

Comment: You should also just write it out in terms of the entries of $A$, $X$, and $Y$.

Comment: Do you know about positive definite matrices and Chelsky decomposition yet?

Comment: @NP-hard of course, thank you!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom not yet, why? thank you

Comment: Meant to write Cholesky.  In any case, see my answer below.

Comment: because the transpose of a real number is the same number

Comment: $f_A(x,y)$ is a real number.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** As explained in the comments above, we can show that $A$ must be symmetric by noting that $f_A(X,Y) = [f_A(X,Y)]^T$.

As for the other conditions: write $X = (x_1,x_2)^T$.  Note that if we assume that $A$ is symmetric, we have
$$
f_A(X,X) = A_{11}x_{1}^2 + 2A_{12} x_1x_2 + A_{22}x_2^2 = 
x_2^2 \left( 
A_{11}\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^2 + 2A_{12} \left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right) + A_{22}\right)
$$
Now, under which conditions on the elements do we have:

- $f_A(X,X) \geq 0$ for all $X$
- $f_A(X,X) = 0$ if and only if $X = 0$

It helps to consider the *discriminant* of the quadratic function $g\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)$.